# How to set the index value as 0 for the array in php?

Tags: php

I am working on my php to fetch the data to store them in an array. I have got a problem with the index value in the array, because the index value will start with 1 then it will count it up to 2, 3, 4...etc which it should start with 0 then 1, 2 3...etc, because I am using `$i = 0;` to start with zero as default.

Here is what I use that the index value start with 1:

```
if(isset($structure->parts) && count($structure->parts)) {

    for($i = 0; $i < count($structure->parts); $i++) {

        if (($structure->parts[$i]->ifdisposition) && ($structure->parts[$i]->disposition == 'attachment')) {

            foreach($structure->parts[$i]->parameters as $object) {
                if(strtolower($object->attribute) == 'name') {
                    $attachments[$i]['is_attachment'] = true;
                    $attachments[$i]['name'] = $object->value;
                    $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = '';
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I have tried to change from `$i++` to `$i` and I tried to put `$i++` in the for loop, but it didn't work.

Output:

```
Array ( [1] => Array ( [is_attachment] => 1 [name] => 2019-01-23 (1).rar [attachment] => ) [2] => Array ( [is_attachment] => 1 [name] => email.zip [attachment] => ) )
```

It should be:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [is_attachment] => 1 [name] => 2019-01-23 (1).rar [attachment] => ) [1] => Array ( [is_attachment] => 1 [name] => email.zip [attachment] => ) )
```

Here is the full code:

```
<?php

require_once "Mail.php";
require_once('Mail/IMAPv2.php');

$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';
$mailserver = '{imap.domain.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX';
$mailbox = imap_open($mailserver, $username, $password) or die("Can't connect: " . imap_last_error());
$key = "key";
$email_number = openssl_decrypt(hex2bin('477'),'AES-128-CBC', $key);
$attach_id = $_GET['attid'];

/* get information specific to this email */
$overview = imap_fetch_overview($mailbox, $email_number, 0);

$message = imap_fetchbody($mailbox, $email_number, 2);

/* get mail structure */
$structure = imap_fetchstructure($mailbox, $email_number);
$attachments = array();
$attachment_number = 0;  

if(isset($structure->parts) && count($structure->parts)) {

    for($i = 0; $i < count($structure->parts); $i++) {

        if (($structure->parts[$i]->ifdisposition) && ($structure->parts[$i]->disposition == 'attachment')) {

            foreach($structure->parts[$i]->parameters as $object) {
                if(strtolower($object->attribute) == 'name') {
                    $attachments[$i]['is_attachment'] = true;
                    $attachments[$i]['name'] = $object->value;
                    $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = '';
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
```

I am unable to find out why the index value have always start with 1 when it should have start with zero then 1, 2, 3 as it get counting up the value each time.

Can you please show me an example how I can start the index value with 0 as a default then count it up to 1, then 2, 3, 4, 5...etc when I am using `$i++`?

Thank you.

Comment: Probably because `$structure->parts[0]` does not match `$structure->parts[$i]->disposition == 'attachment'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because `$structure->parts[0]` does not match `$structure->parts[$i]->disposition == 'attachment'` in all cases.

Only create a new item in your array when one is correct and dont use the loop counter use a simpe `$arr[]` contruct to create the next occurance

```
$attachments = array();

if(isset($structure->parts) && count($structure->parts)) {
    foreach ($structure->parts as $part) {
        if (($part->ifdisposition) && ($part->disposition == 'attachment')) {

            foreach($part->parameters as $obj) {
                if(strtolower($obj->attribute) == 'name') {

                    $t['is_attachment'] = true;
                    $t['name'] = $obj->value;
                    $t['attachment'] = '';

                    $attachments[] = $t
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
foreach($structure->parts[$i]->parameters as $object) {
            if(strtolower($object->attribute) == 'name') {
                $attachment['is_attachment'] = true;
                $attachment['name'] = $object->value;
                $attachment['attachment'] = '';
                $attachments[]=$attachment;

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know why indexes of array start with 1 and not 0, show us definition of array.
But you can also loop array with unknown keys with for loop by getting array keys with PHP [array_keys](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) function

```
$this->arr = [1 => 'one', 2 => 'two', 3 => 'three'];
    $keys = array_keys($this->arr);
    for($i = 0; $i < count($keys); $i++) {
        $value = $this->arr[$keys[$i]];
        echo 'val: ' .$value.'<br>';
    }
```

Or you can wrap two foreaches into another

```
foreach($structure->parts as $key => $part){

        $part->ifdisposition = true;
        $part->disposition = 'attachment';
        if (($part->ifdisposition) && ($part->disposition == 'attachment')) {

            foreach($part->parameters as $object) {
                if(strtolower($object->attribute) == 'name') {
                    $attachments[$key]['is_attachment'] = true;
                    $attachments[$key]['name'] = $object->value;
                    $attachments[$key]['attachment'] = '';
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Another option is to remap keys of array, using [array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) but you array will be altered, so if you need the original array, you can cache it into another variable.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
$attachments[$i]['is_attachment'] = true;
$attachments[$i]['name'] = $object->value;
$attachments[$i]['attachment'] = '';
```

You are setting the key to `$i`, so the first element in `$structure->parts` to match the criteria is the second element in the loop. To set the `$attachments` array starting at zero, you simply need to let PHP create the keys itself:

```
$attachments[] = ['is_attachment' => true, 'name' => $object->value, 'attachment' => ''];
```